Contact forces in partially inelastic collisions
Consider a collision of two objects $A$ and $B$ in one dimension. $A$ is perfectly elastic and is moving towards B with some velocity. $B$ is rigid and stationary. Let's say that the system is conservative, so there's no energy lost to e.g. sound or heat.
There are situations where $A$ is bouncing back from $B$. Since velocity is continuous and $A$ changes direction, there must be some point in time where $v_A$ is zero. This also means that there's a period of time where $v_B > v_A$.
What I'm trying to understand: If after a time, $B$'s velocity is greater than $A$'s, then $B$ is "getting away" from $A$, which would mean to me that they are no longer in contact. Yet on the macroscopic scale I can see that $A$ is still decelerating and bouncing back, so contact forces must still be applied somehow.
What is wrong in the above description? / What would be a correct description of the system while the objects are in contact?

The biggest misconception arises from the idea that during the contact, object B's velocity could become greater than A's while they're still interacting. In reality, during an (partially)elastic collision, while the objects are in contact, they must exert forces on each other.

THE CORRECT DESCRIPTION

ENERGY : In a partially inelastic collision, some of the kinetic energy is lost to deformation, heat, or other forms. This means that after the collision, the total kinetic energy of the system will be lower than before, though momentum is still conserved.

where($v_a=v_b$) : In your description, you're concerned about the period when $v_b > v_a$ suggesting that B is "getting away" from A, which implies no contact. This is a misunderstanding. During the collision, while A is slowing down and B is accelerating, their velocities will never differ in a way that suggests B is "getting away" while they are still in contact.


The misunderstanding in your original description comes from thinking that $v_b > v_a$ could happen while the two objects are still in contact. This is not correct. While they are in contact, their velocities remain constrained by the interaction forces. Once they are no longer in contact, B can "get away" from A, and their velocities can differ freely.

I hope this helps you...if u have anymore doubt plz be free to comment here

At the moment when A reaches maximum compression and is about to bounce back, there is a point where both A and B move at the same speed. At this point, the force between them is strongest, and A begins to move backward while B moves forward.
